# Django redirect using reverse() to a URL that relies on query strings

Tags: django, django-views

I'm writing a django application with a URL like 'http://localhost/entity/id/?overlay=other_id'.  Where id is the primary key of the particular entity and overlay is an optional query parameter for a second entity to be overlaid in the display.  The user can only ever update an entity when viewing objects through an overlay.  When POSTing to /update/id, I want to redirect back to /entity/id, but I don't want to lose my query parameter during the redirect, as the change in view would be jarring.

For example, I've got the following in my url.py:

```
...
(r'^update/(?P<id>.+)/(?P<overlay_id>.+)/$', 'update'),
(r'^entity/(?P<id>.+)/$', 'view'),
...
```

Because overlay_id is required when updating, it's part of the URL, not a query parameter.  In the django view I want to redirect after a successful POST and use reverse() to avoid referencing URLs in my python code.  The general idea is:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(
  reverse('views.view',
    kwargs={
      'id': id,
    },
  )
)
```

But how do I pass my query parameter though reverse?

Thanks,
Craig

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you just check for an `overlay_id` and add it to your url?

```
redirect_url = reverse( ... )
extra_params = '?overlay=%s' % overlay_id if overlay_id else ''
full_redirect_url = '%s%s' % (redirect_url, extra_params)
return HttpResponseRedirect( full_redirect_url )
```

Comment: Yep, I realized this while brushing my teeth a second ago.  Sometimes I wish Python had type signatures, as this would've been obvious if reverse() was declared to return a string.  Thanks.

Comment: I usually get those ah ha moments in the shower the next morning.  You might find that pdb (or ipdb) helps in cases where you pine for type signatures.  Try throwing `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` into your code some time.  http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 23):

You can use a [Django QueryDict object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict):

```
from django.http import QueryDict

# from scratch
qdict = QueryDict('',mutable=True)

# starting with our existing query params to pass along
qdict = request.GET.copy()

# put in new values via regular dict
qdict.update({'foo':'bar'})

# put it together
full_url = reversed_url + '?' + qdict.urlencode()
```

And of course you could write a convenience method for it similar to the previous answer.

Comment: `update()` will append the value to the query string so any existing 'foo' value will remain instead of being replaced.  If you want to replace any existing value then you use `qdict['foo'] = 'bar'`.

Answer (score 4):

Query string args should be properly escaped and not just concatenated!

Building an url with query string by string concatenation is as bad idea as building SQL queries by string concatenation. It is complicated, unelegant and especially dangerous with a user provided (untrusted) input. Unfortunately Django does not offer an easy possibility to pass query parameters to the [reverse](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) function.

Python standard [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) however provides the desired query string encoding functionality.

In my [application](http://www.mobile-web-consulting.de/post/3921808264/construct-url-with-query-parameters-in-django-with) I've created a helper function like this:

```
def url_with_querystring(path, **kwargs):
    return path + '?' + urllib.urlencode(kwargs)
```

Then I call it in the view as follows:

```
quick_add_order_url = url_with_querystring(reverse(order_add),
    responsible=employee.id, scheduled_for=datetime.date.today(),
    subject='hello world!')
# http://localhost/myapp/order/add/?responsible=5&
#     scheduled_for=2011-03-17&subject=hello+world%21
```

Please note the proper encoding of special characters like space and exclamation mark!

Comment: There is no need to go to the trouble of url encoding the query string parameters yourself. HTTPResponseRedirect will do it for you.

Comment: @Declan Shanaghy HTTPResponseRedirect does not offer any query string assembly functionality (django documentation: "The constructor takes a single argument -- the path to redirect to."), so you have to do it yourself. But not with a simple string concatenation as suggested by istruble - this will not work for values containing special characters or whitespace.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't generate the url string yourself. Given your urls.py you can use reverse like so:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
print reverse('view_function_name', kwargs={"id":"id_value", "overlay_id": "overlay_id_value"})

# or to pass view function arguments as an array:
print reverse('view_function_name', args=("id_value","overlay_id_value",))
```

If you use [named url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns), which are great for disconnecting your view functions from url identifiers:

```
# urls.py
...
(r'^update/(?P<id>.+)/(?P<overlay_id>.+)/$', 'update', name="update_foo"),
...
```

Use reverse like so:

```
print reverse("update_foo", kwargs={"id":"id_value", "overlay_id": "overlay_id_value"})
```

Comment: There is _no_way_ that there is any distinction between single quotes and double quotes there.

Comment: Everything but my experience that day of March 27 makes me want to edit my answer per your comment. Can anyone else confirm?

Comment: It is possible that in one instance you forgot the "r" (or 'r' :) ) at the start of the string. Not in these examples, but in others where you're using things like \d, the lack of the 'r' will have python interpret the \d (and others) as special characters, rather than leaving them for the RE engine to find. That is the best guess I Could come up with. If you can actually find the statement that didn't work - before fixing it - we can analyse it.

Comment: I've edited my answer to remove the quotation confusion. Thanks Ch'marr