# Redirect to a url with query string in Django

Tags: python, django

How can I go to a specific URL with parameters like if I have view

```
def search(request):
```

and in urls.py

```
^search/$
```

and what I need to do is to redirect like `search/?item=4`

```
c = {}
render_to_response("search.html",c)
```

works fine, but

```
render_to_response("search.html/?item=" + itemID, c )
```

it says no template found ( I know there is no template like search.html/?item= ) but how can I pass parameters or use query string to redirect?

Comment: render_to_response has nothing to do with redirect!

Comment: I just want to redirect to some url like search/?item=5 (pass query string parameter)
any other way?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Using reverse and passing the name of url we can redirect to url with query string:

#urls.py

```
url(r'^search/$', views.search, name='search_view')
```

#views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, reverse

# in method
return redirect(reverse('search_view') + '?item=4')
```

Comment: This should probably not be the accepted answer. You should use `urlencode` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41875812/3393459)

Comment: If you set the `Location` header manually that's true but if you use `HttpResponseRedirect` or the `redirect` shortcut, it [calls iri_to_uri](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2.4/django/http/response.py#L616) which [calls urlencode for you](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2.4/django/utils/encoding.py#L138) so you don't need to do it yourself.  If fact, if you do it yourself, the URL will get double encoded which mangles it.

Answer (score 16):

I know this question is a bit old, but someone will stumble upon this while searching redirect with query string, so here is my solution:

```
import urllib
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def redirect_params(url, params=None):
    response = redirect(url)
    if params:
        query_string = urllib.urlencode(params)
        response['Location'] += '?' + query_string
    return response

def your_view(request):
    your_params = {
        'item': 4
    }
    return redirect_params('search_view', your_params)
```

Comment: Warning! urllib has been split up in python3. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28906913/9395299). Nevertheless, this solution works very well. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

If you already have a request (with a GET containing some parameters), and you want to redirect to a different view with the same args, kwargs and parameters, we can use the QueryDict object to url encode itself:

```
def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return redirect(
        reverse('your:view:path', args=args, kwargs=kwargs) + 
        '?' + request.GET.urlencode()
    )
```

Comment: Note it's also possible to create your own `QueryDict` instance, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15010861

Answer (score 2):

A more generic option;

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from django.shortcuts import redirect as django_redirect


def redirect(url, *args, params=None, **kwargs):
    query_params = ""
    if params:
        query_params += '?' + urlencode(params)
    return django_redirect(url+query_params, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to another page while carrying along the the current query strings:

`views.py`:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    #get the current query string
    q = request.META['QUERY_STRING']
    return redirect(reverse('search_view') + '?' + q)
```

Comment: Does not work if the search query string has escaped characters.

Comment: request.META['QUERY_STRING'] is allready escaped, works for me.