# 'module' has no attribute 'urlencode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

When I try to follow the [Python Wiki's example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) related to URL encoding:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> params = urllib.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
>>> f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.musi-cal.com/cgi-bin/query", params)
>>> print f.read()
```

An error is raised on the second line:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlencode'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The "2" in your URL.

Answer (score 338, accepted):

`urllib` has been split up in `Python 3`.

The `urllib.urlencode()` function is now [`urllib.parse.urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode),

the `urllib.urlopen()` function is now [`urllib.request.urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen).

Answer (score 44):

```
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
```

Answer (score 5):

You use the Python 2 docs but write your program in Python 3.

Comment: Well it is a tag in your problem and the link points to the Python 2 docs.