# Python Program to call Google Maps api giving error at urllib.urlencode

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I am trying to call Google Map API from Python 3.8.

```
import urllib
import json

serviceurl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?'

while True:
    address = input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1:
        break

    url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({'sensor': 'false',
                                         'address': address})
    print('Retrieving', url)
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print('Retrieved', len(data), 'characters')

    try:
        js = json.loads(str(data))
    except:
        js = None
    if 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':
        print('==== Failure To Retrieve ====')
        print(data)
        continue

    print(json.dumps(js, indent=4))

    lat = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
    lng = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
    print('lat', lat, 'lng', lng)
    location = js['results'][0]['formatted_address']
    print(location)
```

The compilation error is at `urllib.urlencode` and at `urllib.urlopen`..

And it is

Cannot find reference 'urlencode' in 'init_.pyi'

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code. First of all, `urllib` has been split up in Python 3, please check out ['module' has no attribute 'urlencode'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28906859/module-has-no-attribute-urlencode).

Secondly, you need to use the HTTPS protocol in the Geocoding request, and make sure that you use a valid API key:

```
serviceurl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIza****sYjs&'
```

Thirdly, replace `json.loads(str(data))` with just `json.loads(data)`.

Full amended code below:

```
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import json

serviceurl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIza****sYjs&'

while True:
    address = input('Enter location: ')
    if len(address) < 1:
        break

    url = serviceurl + urllib.parse.urlencode({'sensor': 'false',
                                               'address': address})
    print('Retrieving', url)
    uh = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print('Retrieved', len(data), 'characters')
    try:
        js = json.loads(data)
    except:
        js = None
    if 'status' not in js or js['status'] != 'OK':
        print('==== Failure To Retrieve ====')
        print(data)
        continue

    print(json.dumps(js, indent=4))

    lat = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"]
    lng = js["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
    print('lat', lat, 'lng', lng)
    location = js['results'][0]['formatted_address']
    print(location)
```

Output for e.g. "paris,france":

```
Enter location: paris,france
Retrieving https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=AIza****sYjs&sensor=false&address=paris%2Cfrance
Retrieved 1690 characters
{
    "results": [
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "Paris",
                    "short_name": "Paris",
                    "types": [
                        "locality",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "Paris",
                    "short_name": "Paris",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_2",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "\u00cele-de-France",
                    "short_name": "IDF",
                    "types": [
                        "administrative_area_level_1",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "France",
                    "short_name": "FR",
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "Paris, France",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 48.9021449,
                        "lng": 2.4699208
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 48.815573,
                        "lng": 2.224199
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 48.856614,
                    "lng": 2.3522219
                },
                "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 48.9021449,
                        "lng": 2.4699208
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 48.815573,
                        "lng": 2.224199
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "ChIJD7fiBh9u5kcRYJSMaMOCCwQ",
            "types": [
                "locality",
                "political"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
lat 48.856614 lng 2.3522219
Paris, France
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did exactly as you said but i am getting a message.{
   "error_message" : "The provided API key is invalid.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Comment: Of course. You need to replace "AIza****sYjs" with your own API key. I'm assuming that you have a valid API key that belongs to a project that has billing enabled and Geocoding API enabled.

Comment: So how will I get a valid API key? I need to purchase it from google maps??

Comment: I recommend you follow Google's get started guide https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started