# Python Pastebin api (edited)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pastebin

(Edited)
I just installed [PastebinAPI](https://pypi.org/project/Pastebin/)
and got an error urllib has no attribute urlopen/urlencode
I went to the pastebin api file myself and I'm wondering if I should change the line

```
import urllib

#to
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
```

I don't know if that's safe so I'm asking here.
As I said I just installed the api so here's my current code

```
from pastebin import PastebinAPI

pasteBin = PastebinAPI()
my_key = pasteBin.generate_user_key(my_dev-key, my-username, my-password)
print(my_key)
```

I found some other useful links like
[Request Pastebin Example](https://www.google.com/urlsa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi51umNqZvtAhWCUMAKHZDACHkQFjABegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpastebin.com%2FasRbutde&usg=AOvVaw0tjkeq0mg7WVKDnCfkBOmL): Should I just use request instead of the api?
[Urllib Pastebin class](https://www.google.com/urlsa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjolsPHq5vtAhVSuXEKHZv0DIQQFjADegQICRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgist.github.com%2Fm8r0wn%2Fecf9c7b5f1a38db8de37f3425e4b4782&usg=AOvVaw2uVjW-Wa2UJCJwxILgfNyj): Thinking of using this if the api doesn't work. Tho they have the same problem with urlopen and urlencode

Okay I've tried changing the urllib to urllib.request/parse but a new error shows
TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.

What does it mean? So confused.
Is the api outdated? If so can someone link me a dated api?

Here's the full error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(My-Name)\PycharmProjects\Project\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    key = pastebin.generate_user_key('(my-key)', '(username)', '(password)')
  File "C:\Users\(My-Name)\PycharmProjects\Project\venv\lib\site-packages\pastebin.py", line 574, in generate_user_key
    request_string = urllib.request.urlopen(self._api_login_url, urllib.parse.urlencode(argv))
  File "C:\Users\(My-Name)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\(My-Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 514, in open
    req = meth(req)
  File "C:\Users\(My-Name)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1273, in do_request_
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should do this when you are working with Python 3.

Based on this
question: ['module' has no attribute 'urlencode'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28906913/10499751), try the following:

> `urllib` has been split up in `Python 3`.
>
> The `urllib.urlencode()` function is now [`urllib.parse.urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode),
>
> the `urllib.urlopen()` function is now [`urllib.request.urlopen()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen).

Comment: I changed but it gave me another error (see bottom of page)