# Django, URL redirecting to same template with request params

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

The initial page on login is ReviewList. It displays each Review item and each review has a Like button. The objective is that when you Like a review, it increments the Like count by 1 and redirects to the same template. Upon doing so, the Like button becomes an Unlike Button, which then decrements the Like count by 1 on click. The actual Like/Unlike logic works fine but I'm having trouble with passing a GET request back to the ReviewList on redirect. Ultimately, I want to pass context['liked'] to the template so then I can do a conditional on whether it displays Like or Unlike. Here is what I have:

**views.py**

```
class ReviewList(ListView):
    model = Review

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ReviewList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['now'] = timezone.now()
        """ Checks if user has liked any reviews. If the user has, then context['liked'] is true, else false. This
        will get passed in to template so that the like button will turn into a unlike button and vice versa  """
        try:
            user_liked = Like.objects.get(user=user, review_id=self.request.GET['review_id']))
        except:
            user_liked = None

        if user_liked:
            liked = True
        else:
            liked = False
        context['liked'] = liked

        return context
...
...

def like(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        review = get_object_or_404(Review, id=id)
        like = Like.objects.get_or_create(review_id=review.id)

        try:
            user_liked = Like.objects.get(user=user, review_id=review.id)
        except:
            user_liked = None

        if user_liked:
            user_liked.total_likes -= 1
            user_liked.user.remove(request.user)
            user_liked.save()

        else:
            list(like)
            like[0].user.add(request.user)
            like[0].total_likes += 1
            like[0].save()

    return redirect(reverse_lazy('reviews:review_list'), review.id)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from apps.reviews import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<review_id>\d+)|$', views.ReviewList.as_view(), name='review_list'),
    url(r'^new/$', views.ReviewCreate.as_view(), name='new'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ReviewDetail.as_view(), name='show'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ReviewUpdate.as_view(), name='edit'),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ReviewDelete.as_view(), name='delete'),
    url(r'^like/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.like, name='like'),

)
```

**UPDATED**

Instead of having my like button redirect to it's current page, I just decided to ajaxify the like button. Save alot of headache.

**views.py**

```
def like(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user = request.user
        review = get_object_or_404(Review, id=request.GET['review_id'])
        like = Like.objects.get_or_create(review_id=review.id)

        try:
            user_liked = Like.objects.get(user=user, review_id=review.id)
        except:
            user_liked = None

        if user_liked:
            user_liked.total_likes -= 1
            user_liked.user.remove(request.user)
            user_liked.save()
            likes = user_liked.total_likes

        else:
            list(like)
            like[0].user.add(request.user)
            like[0].total_likes += 1
            like[0].save()
            likes = like[0].total_likes

    return HttpResponse(likes)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from apps.reviews import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.ReviewList.as_view(), name='review_list'),
    url(r'^new/$', views.ReviewCreate.as_view(), name='new'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ReviewDetail.as_view(), name='show'),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ReviewUpdate.as_view(), name='edit'),
    url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ReviewDelete.as_view(), name='delete'),
    url(r'^like$', views.like, name='like'),

)
```

**Added review.js**

```
$(function (){

  $('.btn.active').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var rev_id = $(this).attr('data-attr');
    $.get('/reviews/like', { review_id: rev_id}, function(data){
      $('td#review_' + rev_id).html(data);
    });
  });
});
```

**snippet from review_list.html**

```
<td id='review_{{review.id}}' class="likes">
      {% if review.like_set.all|length != 0 %}
        {% for like in review.like_set.all %}
          {{ like.total_likes }}
        {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
        0
      {% endif %}
    </td>
```

Comment: Have you looked in to doing this using ajax? It would make your logic smoother and eliminate your current problem.

Comment: yeah I was planning on doing it through Ajax after I get this working properly. I'm a Django newbie, so it's more for me having a thorough understanding of how Django works

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477090/django-redirect-using-reverse-to-a-url-that-relies-on-query-strings

Comment: You might want to fix the pattern terminator in your first url. You've used a pipe - | - instead of a forward slash - /. This would cause your first pattern to fail.

Comment: Limelights, thanks. Looks very close to what I need

Comment: Brandon, actually the pipe is intentional. I wanted to either have a review id passed in or none at all. So by default, it should go to /reviews/ if a like isn't clicked or if clicked have a review id appended to the url like /review?=<review_id>. I'm gonna need to rebuild the url